# findOneAndUpdate - Update the first object in array that has specific attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object that has attributes. This includes an array of other Objects that have their own attributes.

```
Lobby:
  --> "a": "b"
  --> "c": "d"
  --> Players:[
         --> 0
           --> "x": "23"
           --> "status": "ready"
         --> 1
           --> "x": "54"
           --> "status": "open"
         --> 2
           --> "x": "16"
           --> "status": "open"
```

How would I go about updating the first Player Object that has `"status": "open"` (in this case 1) to a new object?

For example:

```
player = {
            x: "125",
            status: 'joined'
         };
```

Comment: (use $ op)  in mongo shell db.collection.update( { _d : x, 'player.status' : 'open'}, { $set : {player.* : { // your new player } } }

Comment: @Disposer And how would I do this in Mongoose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a working solution!

```
Game.findOneAndUpdate({'a': 'b', 'Players.status': 'open'}, { $set : { 'Players.$': player} },
function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```