# FindOneAndUpdate not updating nested field with passed in parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updating, meanjs

I am trying to create a service that can be used to update nested fields in a Mongoose model. In the following example I am trying to set the field 'meta.status' to the value 2. This is the service:

```
angular.module('rooms').factory('UpdateSvc',['$http', function($http)
{
    return function(model, id, args)
    {
            var url = '/roomieUpdate/' + id;

            $http.put(url, args).then(function(response)
            {
                response = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            });
    }
}]);
```

This is how it is called in the controller:

```
var newStatus = {'meta.$.status' : 2};
var update = UpdateSvc("roomie", sessionStorage.getItem('userID'), newStatus);
```

And this is the model:

```
var RoomieSchema = new Schema(
{
    meta: 
    {
        created:
        {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        status:
        {
            type: Number,
            default: '1',
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the route:

```
app.put('/roomieUpdate/:id', function(req,res)
{
    var id = req.params.id;
    Roomie.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)},

        req.body,
        { new : true },
        function(err, doc)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.json(doc);
            console.log(doc);
        });
});
```

The argument is received correctly, but I can't seem to get this to work. I am not even getting an error message. console.log(doc) simply prints out the object and the field meta.status remains '1'. I have done a direct Mongo search on the target object to make sure that I wasn't just reading the old document. I've tried a great many things like separating the key and value of req.body and use {$set:{key:value}}, but result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

`findOneAndUpdate()` by default will return the *old* document, not the new (updated) document.

For that, you need to set the [`new`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) option:

```
Roomie.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
}, req.body, { new : true }, function(err, doc) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also yields the same result. I added the {new:true} clause since it is now in my code. I also had upsert:true previously which also didn't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, var newStatus = {'meta.$.status' : 2}; should have been var newStatus = {'meta.status' : 2}; The document now updates correctly.

The reason the $ was there in the first place was probably based on this thread:
[findOneAndUpdate - Update the first object in array that has specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775885/findoneandupdate-update-the-first-object-in-array-that-has-specific-attribute)

or another of the many threads I read through about this issue. I had tried several solutions with and without it, but couldn't get anything to go right.