# On findOneAndUpdate check that item with parameter existing in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have model:

```
var UserSchema  = new Schema({
    name : {type: String, required: true},
    devices : [
        { uuid : {type: String, required: true},
        token : {type: String, required: true}
    ]
})
```

When user connects from another (new) device I want to push new device to devices array, otherwise, when user updates token, I need to update existing array item.

So, what I am doing:

```
    User.findOneAndUpdate({name: 'John'}, { 
        $push: {devices : { uuid : '12345', token : 'TEST_TOKEN'}}
        }, {safe: true, new : true}, function(err, user) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(user);          
    });
```

I think that I need somehow check that device UUID does not exist in array, and if exist update token, otherwise create new device item and push to array

I already try to create uuid index with unique: true

```
{ uuid : {type: String, required: true, index : {unique: true}}
```

But this index sets to all collection. And if I have another user with same UUID, I cant add new.

How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775885/findoneandupdate-update-the-first-object-in-array-that-has-specific-attribute), the problem was in that i didnt know how to update arrays in models by using findOneAndUpdate function.